# backslash is escaped while adding shared printer name in php

Tags: php, escaping

I am having problem in passing Shared Printer Path via PHP
for example
My printer is located at "\NISHANT\epson2"
but when I want to print through this printer using printer_open function i have to mention it as "\\\NISHANT\\epson2" otherwise it is failed to print.

Can anyone tell me is there any function to make text accordingly, please bare in mind "\e" is an escaped string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function to escape all relevant characters or something like

```
str_replace($name, "\\", "\\\\")
```

for just backslashes.